# Creating sublists from one bigger list

Tags: r, list, subset, sublist

I am writing my Thesis in R and I would like, if possible, some help in a problem that I have.

I have a table, which is called tkalp, with 2 columns and 3001 rows and after a 'subset' command that I wrote this table contains now 1084 rows and called kp. Some values of kp are:[image]

As you can see some values from the column **V1** are continuously with step = 2 and some are not.

So my difficulty is:

**1.** I would like to 'break' this big list/table into smaller lists/tables that contain only continuous numbers. For this difficulty, I tried to implement it with these commands but it didn't go as planned:

```
for (n in 1:nrow(kp)) {
  kp1 <- subset(kp, kp[n+1,1] - kp[n,1])==2)
}
```

**2.** After completing this task I would like to keep only the sublists that contain more than 10 rows.

Any idea or help is more than welcome! Thank you very much

**EDIT**

I have uploaded a picture of my table and I have separated the numbers that I want to be contained in different tables. And I would like to do that for all the original table.[image: kp]

blue  is one smaller table than the original

black another

yellow another

red another

And after I create all those smaller tables I would like to keep only the tables that contain more than 10 numbers. For example I don't want to keep the yellow table since it contains only 4 numbers.

Thank you again

Comment: Please post example of your data (and wanted output) using `dput()` function (not the image) so that we can test our solutions on it.

Comment: Ok, yes i think this is better and more accurate. I have just edited my original post that concludes my table and I have posted one more image to describe what exactly I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
           df <- data.frame(V1=c(1,3,5,10,12,14, 20, 22), V2=runif(8))
            df$diff <- c(2,diff(df$V1))
            df$numSubset <- cumsum(df$diff != 2) + 1
            iter <- seq(max(df$numSubset))
            purrr::map(iter, function(i) filter(df, numSubset == i))
            listOfSubsets <-  purrr::map(iter, function(i) dplyr::filter(df, numSubset == i))
```

Then you loop through the list and select only those you want. Btw purrr also provides a means to filter the list you get without looping. Check the documentation of purrr.

Comment: I like your idea and the way that you solve the problem. Can I ask you what is the 'iter' that you mention?

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to paste the line, where "iter" is defined. Now I edited it. "iter" lets you iterate over the "numSubSet"

Answer (score 0):

With base R

```
kp=data.frame(V1=c(seq(8628,8618,by=-2),seq(8576,8566,by=-2),78,76),V2=runif(14))
kp$diffV1=c(-2,diff(kp$V1))/-2
kp$group=cumsum(ifelse(kp$diffV1/-2==1,0,1))+1
lkp=split(kp,kp$group)

# > kp
#      V1         V2 diffV1 group
# 1  8628 0.74304325     -2     1
# 2  8626 0.84658101     -2     1
# 3  8624 0.74540089     -2     1
# 4  8622 0.83551473     -2     1
# 5  8620 0.63605222     -2     1
# 6  8618 0.92702915     -2     1
# 7  8576 0.81978587    -42     2
# 8  8574 0.01661538     -2     2
# 9  8572 0.52313859     -2     2
# 10 8570 0.39997951     -2     2
# 11 8568 0.61444445     -2     2
# 12 8566 0.23570017     -2     2
# 13   78 0.58397923  -8488     3
# 14   76 0.03634809     -2     3
```